# Do corrupted pdfs become a virus?

Tags: email

Does a corrupted pdf still become a virus if the binary for a virus still exists but the pdf structure is corrupted?

Comment: How do I get -3 for asking a question. You guys are harsh

Comment: you get -3 when your question is so garbled, that it's unreadable

Comment: the answer is obvious: viruses need to be executed - if they cannot be executed, then they are not a virus - which means, according to your question, it depends on how the PDF is corrupted

Comment: I suspect you are asking if a PDF *containing* a virus remains capable of harm if the PDF file itself is corrupt. However what you actually asked is whether the one can be transmuted in the other - which is semantic gibberish.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, a PDF that contains a virus is corrupt.  (I'm ignoring the case where a PDF might contain a JPG or font that houses a virus.)  So yes, a virus in a corrupted PDF is still viable and can infect a client that parses it.